# Singaporean Makan <Hoken???> Centre <<transcript question / listening question

Tags: pronunciation-vs-spelling, foreign-phrases

Can anyone who is familiar with Asian cuisine help me with a food word?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WYFe2-hqA2Q

*"One thing unites all Singaporeans; food.  It’s the national obsession.  For an authentic Singaporean Makan experience, follow the satay smoke to the nearest < Hoken?> centre..."*

What is that word at 1:54?  Hoka Centre?  Hoken Centre?

Comment: _Makan_ is the Malay word for 'eat'. _Rumah makan_ 'house eat' is one name for 'restaurant'. Malay is one of the official languages of Singapore. Oh, and it's probly _Hokkien_.

Comment: "For an authentic Singaporean 'Makan' experience, follow the satay smoke to the nearest **hawkers** center." (emphasis mine) src: http://studyfun.ru/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA/Singapore%20Travel%20Guide/  studyFun *Singapore Travel Guide*

Comment: @JohnLawler Hokkien is a dialect of Chinese. Chinese are the majority race in Singapore with a very high proportion of Hokkien speakers. But you are right that *Makan*  is a Malay word - to eat. (Malaysia and Singapore are my second home). Hokkien, incidentally, is very distinct from other local Chinese dialects such as Cantonese, Hakka etc. (I think the tonal structure is different) and they rarely understand one another.

Comment: Ah, _hawker centres_. Yes, great food. I first encountered them in S'pore in '86, shortly after they started out. Happy memories of polyglot meals, some Chinese, some Indian, some Malay.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, makan is a Malay word meaning "eat".
The word before " centre" in the video is probably "hawker". A hawker centre sells food like a food court.

Comment: As a frequent visitor to Malaysia and Singapore, I would think you are spot on with this.

Comment: I'm going with 'hawker'.  Thank you!  The absence of an /n/ at the end eliminates 'Hokkien' as an option.  Because of the  elided final /r/ for hawker (she pronouces it 'hawka') -- that makes sense to me. Thanks again ))